# Difference between pgpool `primary` and watchdog `MASTER` versus the load_balance_node

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I have a pgpool with 3 nodes.
I have a confusion between the pgpool `primary` and the watchdog `MASTER` and the node designated `load_balance_node`

In my setup, the pgpool `primary` node (according to `show pool_nodes` output) is :
**10.108.104.31** (This is also the load_balance_node)

While the `MASTER` node, according to pgpool watchdog, is: **10.108.104.32**
And the cluster virtual IP is attached to this node.

### Questions:

1. What is the meaning of the terms watchdog `MASTER`, pgpool `primary` and `load_balance_node`?
2. Shouldn't the **load_balance_node** hold the virtual IP for the cluster?
3. During failover, Is the 'primary' or 'MASTER' or 'load_balance_node failure taken into account?
4. What is the difference (or any relation) between the 'primary' and 'MASTER' and load_balance_node nodes?

I don't see anything much related to these terms in the pgpool documentation at:
https://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-4.0.4/

Below is the pool status for reference:

```
psql -h delegateIP -p 9999 -U pgpool postgres -c "show pool_nodes"
Password for user pgpool:
 node_id |   hostname    | port | status | lb_weight |  role   | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | last_status_change
---------+---------------+------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------
 0       | 10.108.104.31 | 5432 | up     | 0.333333  | primary | 0          | true              | 0                 | 2023-05-12 12:07:13
 1       | 10.108.104.32 | 5432 | up     | 0.333333  | standby | 0          | false             | 0                 | 2023-05-12 12:07:13
 2       | 10.108.104.33 | 5432 | down   | 0.333333  | standby | 0          | false             | 0                 | 2023-05-12 12:07:13
(3 rows)
```

And the Watchdog info:

```
pcp_watchdog_info -h localhost -vw -U pgpool
Watchdog Cluster Information
Total Nodes          : 3
Remote Nodes         : 2
Quorum state         : QUORUM EXIST
Alive Remote Nodes   : 2
VIP up on local node : NO
Master Node Name     : vm-104-32.eng.dev.com:9999 Linux vm-104-32.eng.dev.com
Master Host Name     : 10.108.104.32

Watchdog Node Information
Node Name      : vm-104-31.eng.dev.com:9999 Linux vm-104-31.eng.dev.com
Host Name      : vm-104-31.eng.dev.com
Delegate IP    : 10.108.104.34
Pgpool port    : 9999
Watchdog port  : 9000
Node priority  : 1
Status         : 7
Status Name    : STANDBY

Node Name      : vm-104-32.eng.dev.com:9999 Linux vm-104-32.eng.dev.com
Host Name      : 10.108.104.32
Delegate IP    : 10.108.104.34
Pgpool port    : 9999
Watchdog port  : 9000
Node priority  : 1
Status         : 4
Status Name    : MASTER

Node Name      : vm-104-33.eng.dev.com:9999 Linux vm-104-33.eng.dev.com
Host Name      : 10.108.104.33
Delegate IP    : 10.108.104.34
Pgpool port    : 9999
Watchdog port  : 9000
Node priority  : 1
Status         : 7
Status Name    : STANDBY
```